# Row update from Datagridview by textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to update my data in the DataGridView (loaded from XML)

```
  private void dgv_AgendaAfspraken_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       DataGridViewRow dr = dgv_AgendaAfspraken.SelectedRows[0];
       dtp_Date.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       cbx_begeleider.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       tbx_opleider.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       tbx_bedrijf.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
       tbx_periode.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    }
```

How do I update these results from the TextBoxes (when I'm changing it) from the same record I just picked them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialize a variable to save your row index:

```
int selectedRow;
```

and assign it your selected row:

```
selectedRow = dgv_AgendaAfspraken.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Then you can just pass the parameters through `SetValues` method to reset them:

```
dgv_AgendaAfspraken.Rows[selectedRow].SetValues(dtp_Date.Text, cbx_begeleider.Text,  tbx_opleider.Text, tbx_bedrijf.Text, tbx_periode.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update from the textboxes ..

```
dr.Cells[0].Value = convert.toint32(dtp_Date.Text);
dr.Cells[1].Value = convert.toint32(cbx_begeleider.Text);
dr.Cells[2].Value = convert.toint32(tbx_opleider.Text);
dr.Cells[3].Value = convert.toint32(tbx_bedrijf.Text);
dr.Cells[4].Value = convert.toint32(tbx_periode.Text);
```