# How to make DataGridView to "increase" and not duplicate

Tags: c#, winforms

**I have a method with 3 arguments, to add rows to DataGridView:**

```
public void DGVadd(string item, int count, int price)
        {
            DataGrid.Rows.Add(item, count, price);
            DataGrid.Update();
        }
```

**I call the method with a simple click on buttons:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DGVadd("item1", 1, 10);
        }
```

**The question is:** How should I do that the Items with the same name won't take multiple rows in the DataGridView, only 1 and make the "count" and the "price" increase?

Thx for your time!

Comment: Hmmm… could you not loop through the grids data and check to see if there is already an “item1” in the grid? If there is... then you would know what row to update the count and price.

Comment: Use a specialized source of data (a class object) that provides an `Add()` method which considers duplicate Items based on an Identifier (the Item Type), so it can add to the internal List if the Item is unique, otherwise, sum the values to an existing Item with the same Identifier. Each Item is a class object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` -- Otherwise, loop the source of data you have or the Rows of your DataGridView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row update from Datagridview by textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900898/) and [How to Edit/Update a row in DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647918/) and [Updating DataGridView Selected Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299537/) and [how to update row in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135737/)

Comment: [Related resources for DataGridView](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/topics/datagridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would require to go through the Rows of your DataGrid and check if the item exist's.

Haven't worked with WinForms for a long time but would be something like this (its just a pseudo code)

```
DGVadd(string item, int count, int price)
{
    bool newRow = true;
    foreach (DataRow row in DataGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.item.Equals(item)
        {
            row.count += count;
            row.price += price;
            newRow = false;
        }
    }
    if (newRow)
    {
        DataGrid.Rows.Add(item, count, price);
    }
    DataGrid.Update();
}
```

Remenber this is just a pseudo code with the logic that I'm referring